# Android Unit Test of Rotation Fails to Find Control

Tags: android, junit, instrumentation

So I have a test where I have set the value of a label, that passes. I noticed the label was blank after rotating so I made a unit test. Problem is that the unit test fails, even though I found the reason the label was blank, and it is no longer blank. After rotation, for some reason, accessing the TextView by ID no longer works, it returns a null.

```
@MediumTest
public void testThatLabelsRestoredAfterSwitchingToLandscape(){
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();

    assertThat(textFor(R.id.location), is("Los Angeles"));

}
```

The textFor method just does null checking, but here it is:

```
private String textFor(int id) {
    TextView text = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(id);
    return text != null && text.getText() != null ? text.getText().toString() : null;
}
```

text is null.

One other not super surprising detail: if the device was in landscape mode then the test passes.

Also, I inserted a sleep into the test after the rotation and you can see the control with the target value.

Comment: There could be different layout resource files for portrait and landscape, and it's possible that the orientation you're switching to is missing R.id.location. Maybe check that?

Comment: No, they are the same. Ok, so I found the problem: the activity is being destroyed!! So it's a different activity after rotation. Trying to figure this out. Apparently the Robotium guys already did figure it out and they sandpaper over this cause it works in their version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem where getActivity() returned a reference to destroyed Activity on layout change. If used Robotium solo.getCurrentActivity() instead, it works ok.